# Azure Data Explorer - Problem with Generated Sample

Tags: c#, azure-data-explorer, sample, vector-database

I am still struggling with QuckStart example app despite that:

I created ADX Cluster on Azure and I have its URL and its ingestion URI
I also created Database
I modified kusto_sample_config.json file and set the above URIs and DBA name in it. I left the rest of the parameters unchanged in this file.
When I run, first of all the credential prompt is confusing:

*Step 1: You will be prompted twice for credentials during this script. Please return to the console after authenticating.
Press any key to proceed with this operation...*

I type my username followed by Return and the app control then goes until I break on the following line. Inside the adminClient there is DefaultDatabaseName member and its value is "NetDefaultDB". When I execute the line:

**await PreIngestionQueryingAsync(config, adminClient, queryProvider);**

I get another prompt:

*Step 2: Alter-merge existing table 'GptModelTrainerTestDB.SampleTable' to align with the provided schema
Press any key to proceed with this operation...*

But by that time, I already see exceptions in the Output window, starting with:

```
StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: 
System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  x-ms-client-request-id: KI.GetIngestionResources;33efc055-3d4c-46b1-8d91-9a640cc027d1;0
  x-ms-activity-id: efee8b30-01db-4f0c-aa01-8480ae26c3a2
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=2592000; includeSubDomains
  Date: Fri, 07 Jul 2023 00:10:14 GMT
  Server: Kestrel
  WWW-Authenticate: Bearer authorization_uri=""https://login.microsoftonline.com/common"", 
  error=""invalid_token"", error_description=""The issuer '(null)' is invalid""
  Content-Length: 0
}
```

So, I went to this page of ADX on GitHub and followed the instructions.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-kusto-samples-dotnet/tree/master/client/QuickStart

Then I downloaded and built the source. I also changed the authentication giving the Azure System the authority to authenticate... I also created *GssTable*, which reflected in the generated source code that I downloaded.

This time, I had to fix a bug during deserialization of generated JSON file (part of the generates source code), and eventually, when it finally ran, I got:

*Script failed with error: Client error while trying to execute command '.create table GssTable (data:string)' on database 'GptModelTrainerTestDB'
Exception: [0]Kusto.Data.Exceptions.KustoClientApplicationAuthenticationException: Authentication via Kusto.Cloud.Platform.Aad.AadManagedIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider to resource https://gravitystorm.westus2.kusto.windows.net failed.*

Why does it generate authentication error - not idea, and why it tries to create a table that I already created is beyond me...
I personally think MS could do a better job providing a simple working example and explaining it better...

EDIT: When I changed the JSON config file to have:
"useExistingTable": true,

I still got:

*Script failed with error: Client error while trying to execute command '.alter-merge table GssTable (data:string)' on database 'GptModelTrainerTestDB'
Exception: [0]Kusto.Data.Exceptions.KustoClientApplicationAuthenticationException: Authentication via Kusto.Cloud.Platform.Aad.AadManagedIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider to resource https://gravitystorm.westus2.kusto.windows.net failed.*

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The sample app itself is not interactive. it simply stops before specific steps to allow the user to see the outputs and be aware of what's going on.

Authentication specifically would either generate a model Azure AD login window which requests your credentials, or it will open up a browser tab doing the same. I did not see you mention this, so it may have been overlook.

When you run into the "prompted for auth" message", you should press a key to continue and look for the prompt auth.

Comment: Yochai, the app neither prompts with Azure AD box, nor opens the browser. Usually, authentication with Azure AD requires that you configure Azure AD with your application (tenant ID, etc.). The problem is that there is no explanation or guidance for what is exactly required from the user to make the app work.... Nevertheless, I will try to configure Azure AD for the app and will post the results here...

Comment: The app (and underlying Kusto SDK) does not require you to configure it at all. Only pass the target cluster address. We did get a few customers complaining about issues AAD prompt auth in the past few weeks which are handled by the AD team. You can consider trying a different authentication method such as AzCli or Device Code login in the mean time. They do require a little more fiddling to run. For AzCli you need to install Azure Cli app and run az login in a shell for the initial auth to succeed. From there on you should not be prompted for a while.

Comment: I did a project for MS Client that was authentication against Azure AD from the desktop Excel Add-In and it required me to make Azure aware of the application, that is, to register the application with Azure AD (plus some other things) and be a member of Azure AD. So I am wondering about your statement... I am passing the cluster URI, but am getting 'Unauthorized'. I will post the entire code here tomorrow...